# Python df saving multiple values in same cell

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a dataframe where the columns are names of students and the rows are grades (each row is a different test). With the following code, I found the max grade for each test

```
df.max(axis=1)
```

However, now I want to know which student received the highest grade. Thus, I want to get the following last column:

```
   Student 1 |  Student 2  |  Student 3  | Max_grade | Which_student
0      3.76  |     3.69    |  2.48       | 3.79      | Student 1
1      1.65  |     4.40    |  6.66       | 6.66      | Student 2
2      3.76  |     3.69    |  2.48       | 3.76      | Student 1
3      5.50  |     5.50    |  1.79       | 5.50      | Student 1, Student 2
4      5.50  |     4.50    |  1.79       | 5.50      | Student 1
```

How can I get the highest value of each row? If 2 students received the same score, I would like to append both names to the last column.

What I did right now was looping over all the values, like:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
       for j in range(len(df.columns)-1):
                    if df.iloc[i,j] == df['Max_grade'].iloc[i]:
                         print(i,total_bets.columns[j])
```

This returns the following:

```
0 Student 1
1 Student 2
2 Student 1
3 Student 1
3 Student 2
4 Student 1
```

However, how can I combine the two students for the third row, and how to save the values in the df?

Answer (score 0):

```
student1 = [3.76, 1.65, 3.76, 5.50, 5.50]
student2 = [3.69, 4.40, 3.69, 5.50, 4.50]
student3 = [2.48, 6.66, 2.48, 1.79, 1.79]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student 1': student1, 'Student 2': student2, 'Student 3': student3})
df['Max_grade'] = df.max(axis=1)
print(df)
whichstudent = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    maxstudent = []
    for j in range(len(df.columns)-1):
        if df.iloc[i,j] == df['Max_grade'].iloc[i]:
            student = df.columns[j]
            maxstudent.append(student)
    whichstudent.append(maxstudent)

whichstudents = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    allstudent = ''
    for j in range(len(whichstudent[i])):
        if len(whichstudent[i]) != 1:
            allstudent = allstudent + ', ' + whichstudent[i][j]
            allstudent = allstudent[1:len(allstudent)]
        else:
            allstudent = whichstudent[i][j]
    whichstudents.append(allstudent)


df['Which_student'] = whichstudents
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Student 1  Student 2  Student 3  Max_grade
0       3.76       3.69       2.48       3.76
1       1.65       4.40       6.66       6.66
2       3.76       3.69       2.48       3.76
3       5.50       5.50       1.79       5.50
4       5.50       4.50       1.79       5.50
   Student 1  Student 2  Student 3  Max_grade         Which_student
0       3.76       3.69       2.48       3.76             Student 1
1       1.65       4.40       6.66       6.66             Student 3
2       3.76       3.69       2.48       3.76             Student 1
3       5.50       5.50       1.79       5.50  Student 1, Student 2
4       5.50       4.50       1.79       5.50             Student 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following code:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    a = []
    for j in range(len(df.columns)-1):
        if df.iloc[i,j] == df['Max_grade'].iloc[i]:
            # df['which_student'].iloc[i].append(df.columns[j], axis=1)
            a.append(df.columns[j])
    df['which_student'].iloc[i] = a
```

Comment: why ``for j in range(len(df.columns)-4):``? Then it will always be ``j=0`` since ``len(df.columns)-4`` is always ``1``.

Comment: You are right @Karina. In my original df I had more columns, that is why I did -4 but in the example above I should not. Thanks for pointing out!